# List from filenames in directory extends with string

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want to create a file which contains filenames from a specific folder (constant) and extend with strings.

For example:
String1 + [1st filename] + String2
String1 + [2nd filename] + String2
...

I can use dir `/b`, but cannot extend with pre- and postfix.

Please help

I tried:

```
chcp 65001>null
dir /b > extended_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /b /a-d "dirname\filemask"') do echo string one %%g string-two
)>filename
```

should create that file for you.

Use `>>` in place of `>` to extend an existing file.

Comment: Thanks! It works. It's more simple than I thought :)